# How to set the background color of specifc cell in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am trying to set the background color of a cell in the html page from a simple javascript. Below is my html and javascript:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>

<!-- CSS -->
<style>
.myTable { 
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  }
.myTable th { 
  background-color: goldenrod;
  color: white; 
  }
.myTable td, 
.myTable th { 
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid goldenrod; 
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">    
<script src ="Json_Development_Test.js">
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<table class="myTable">

    <tr>
        <th>PROJECT</th>
        <th>Service</th>
        <th>PrDC</th>
        <th>DDC</th>
        <th>Last Checked Time(IST)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>
         <div>
          <span id="headerID1">
           <p>Test</p>
           </span>
         </div>
        </td>
        <td>
         <div>
           <span id="header2">
           <p>Test2</p>
           </span>
         </div>
        </td>
        <td>
         <div>
           <p>Test3</p>
         </div>
        </td>
        <td>
         <div>
           <p>Test4</p>
         </div>
        </td>
        <td>
         <div>
           <p>Test5</p>
         </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('All assets are loaded')
  })

document.getElementById('headerID1').bgColor='#003F87'
```

**Expected result:**

I need to change the background color of the span id "headerID1" and following other span id as well.

**Actual result:**

The color is not getting changed and instead I am getting the following errors:

```
HTML1503: Unexpected start tag.
testDesign.html (26,1)

 SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference
Json_Development_Test.js (4,1)

 HTML1512: Unmatched end tag.
testDesign.html (32,1)

 HTML1506: Unexpected token.
testDesign.html (43,2)

2 HTML1530: Text found within a structural table element. Table text may only be placed inside "caption>", "td>", or "th>" elements.
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with this line of code

`document.getElementById('headerID1').style.background = 'blue'`

use

```
document.getElementById('headerID1').bgColor='blue'
```

instead.

Also, HTML structure is wrong too.

Answer (score 3):

Besides some errors related to invalid HTML, as mentioned by others, your background color won't change because you put `<p>` inside `<span>` which doesn't make any sence since `<p>` is a paragraph and `<span>` is a generic inline container for phrasing content. It will work though if you put `<span>` inside `<p>`:

```
<p id="header2">
   <span>...</span>
</p>
```

But if you want to apply background to the entire cell, I recommend you to style the `<td>` element instead. Check the following example:

```js
document.getElementById('headerID1').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
document.getElementById('header2').style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
document.getElementById('header3').style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
```

```css
.myTable { 
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  }
.myTable th { 
  background-color: goldenrod;
  color: white; 
  }
.myTable td, 
.myTable th { 
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid goldenrod; 
  }
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>PROJECT</th>
        <th>Service</th>
        <th>PrDC</th>
        <th>DDC</th>
        <th>Last Checked Time(IST)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
       <div>
        <span id="headerID1">
          <p>BG doesn't work</p>
         </span>
       </div>
      </td>
      <td>
       <div>
         <p id="header2">
          <span>BG works because &lt;span&gt; is inside &lt;p&gt;</span>
         </p>
       </div>
      </td>
      <td id="header3">
       <div>
         <p>BG for entire cell</p>
       </div>
      </td>
      <td>
       <div>
         <p>Test4</p>
       </div>
      </td>
      <td>
       <div>
         <p>Test5</p>
       </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**UPD:** Probably you are getting `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference`  because your `Json_Development_Test.js` script starts executing when the rest document is not rendered yet. You can try to:

1. Put `<script src ="Json_Development_Test.js">` to the bottom of the html
2. Put this line `document.getElementById('headerID1').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';` inside the `window.addEventListener('load', ...)` callback:

   ```
   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
       console.log('All assets are loaded');
       document.getElementById('headerID1').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
   });
   ```

Comment: Hi @Kirill Simonov, after modified with your code, iam still getting following error

'SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference
Json_Development_Test.js (3,1)'
Please let me know what went wrong from my side

Comment: HI @Kirill, i have one more thing which i missed to ask,  the background color of the cell not get updated with the blue color, it only applied to the text. so would like to know how to apply the background color entirely to the cell?

Comment: @hanju take a closer look at my answer: *But if you want to apply background to the entire cell, I recommend you to style the <td> element instead*. Click **Run code snippet** and you will see that `<td id="header3">` has a backgound applied to the entire cell.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. When writing HTML you might want to use an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

A few problems with your code:

1. the `<head>` should go right after the `<html>` tag, and you should close the `<head>` before opening the `<body>`.
2. Delete this line `<div id ="test">`
3. The property you want in your JS is `backgroundColor`, so you would have:

```js
document.getElementById('headerID1').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

Comment: HI jaske2389 and Avishka Kavindu B. Dambawinna i have modified the script accordingly, but still the color is not getting changed and getting following #error
'SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'bgColor' of undefined or null reference
Json_Development_Test.js (4,1)'
Let me know please what went wrong